# Hex character converter converting to wrong char

Tags: c, char, hex, buffer-overflow

I'm working on a buffer overflow attack and I have this code that converts an `0xXX` input to the equivalent 1 byte ASCII char.

```
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin)) {
        char * rest=buffer;
        unsigned char hexVal;
        while (rest[0]!='\0') {
            if (1==sscanf(rest,"0x%2hhx",&hexVal)) {
                printf("%c",hexVal);
                rest+=4;
            } else {
                printf("%c",rest[0]);
                rest++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I give it the input `0x180x850x040x08` (which is the little endian version of `08048518`), it turns into the address`bdbfef18`.
I'm not sure why the address is being interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: How does anything turn into an address here? Where does the address come from? You should see five characters printed - codes 24, 138, 4, 8, and 10 for `'\n'`. That should be the end of it - i.e. no address.